# I need to add Jquery in my Node

Tags: jquery, node.js

How can I include some Jquery features in my Node project? I have the entire site built but I never figured out how to add some Jquery to it.

Comment: Node.js is a server-side language. Jquery is for cross-browser DOM manipulation. Servers don't have DOM. Jquery is not intended for Node.js (unless you're doing virtual DOM, but that's _completely_ different than what it sounds like you're trying to do).

Comment: You should be a little more specific about what you are doing. If you have a Node/Express app, you'll likely want to just include the jQuery script tag in a base template. But people combine them in other ways too, i.e. using webpack and npm to manage dependencies. It's hard to give a good answer without more detail.

Comment: @Mark_M what I’m trying to do is add some animation to the hamburger menu icon in mobile view

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Cheerio:

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

It is a great lib to parse using some jQuery-like syntax.